# Why do we use to detect type of object is function?

Tags: javascript

Why do we use almost in all javascript application like this:

```
if ( typeof Object.create !== 'function' ) {
    Object.create = function( obj ) {
        function F() {};
        F.prototype = obj;
        return new F();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [polyfill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyfill) -- it detects whether a feature of javascript is supported by the current users browser, and if it's not there, defines it so that the other scripts that come with a page will run properly on that browser.

Comment: explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

If your function declared in external js file and you are not sure about that file is successfully loaded, you must need to check before calling it otherwise it will throw error.

Or if you want to check current browser support any particular function or not.